# Dimensional analyse of charge quantity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, charge, dimensional-analysis, coulombs-law

F=m*a

so dimension of F is [$M*L/T^2\\$].

$F = (G*M*m)/r^2\\$

$F = (k*q*Q)/r^2 \\$
Is it right to think that dimension of (q) is same with (m)?

Comment: Note how confusing this can be when we consider both CGS and SI. The presence or absence of $k$ in Coulomb's law changes the *dimensions* of charge. Note especially that it is not a question of units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because $G$ and $k$ do not have the same dimension:

$$[G]=m^3⋅kg^{−1}⋅s^{−2} = N\cdot m^2 \cdot kg^{-2}$$
$$[k]=N \cdot m^2 \cdot C^{-2}$$

The dimensions for q and m also differ:

$$[q]=[Q]=C$$
$$[m]=[M]=kg$$

If you fill these quantities into the equations for gravitational and electrostatic force, you will find that the unit for force is the same in both cases.

Comment: Dimension of F is [$M*L/T^2\\$]. and also $F=k*q*Q/r^2=G*m*M/r^2\\$ so I thought that dimension of force of gravity and charge should be same. Can you explain that the two dimensions are the same even if m and q are different?

Comment: @ABC I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

No, because of the similarities of both equations you may think that, but the key is on the constants.

$G$ is the universal gravitational constant which is $[G]=L^3·M^{-1}·T^{-2}$

and the other, $k$ is the Coulomb's constant which is $[k]=L^3·M·C^{-2}·T^{-2}$

So these are different constant that make different properties of the matter into forces, because of the fundamental interactions.

Comment: Are you sure the units for $k$ are correct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't used N to see in other way that mass is not the same as coulomb

Comment: No problem, I removed my downvote and upvoted instead

Comment: Since ampere is one of the seven fundamental units and coulomb is not, shouldn't we use [$AT$] instead of [$C^{-2}$] (if A is the correct "symbol" (?) for electric current)?